# Some execCommands are not running in my custom WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to create a wysiwyg editor from scratch. I tried using an iframe, but I don´t like 'cause I loose the control over its elements (like images), that I'd like to be able to resize. So I moved to contenteditable div. The issue is that now, I have another problem. Previously I had created my own custom color selectors (fore and back) and font selectors(family and size) so that it would have the color pattern I wanted, in order to integrate it in my personal project.

When I was using the iframe, these custom selectors worked justed fine. However, now, with the contenteditable div, every I click in the selectors' options the editor text is desselected (or so it looks like) and, therefore, the selectors can´t do anything.

With bold, italic, ... buttons the functionality is 100% operational.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="TextEditor">
        <div id="TextTitle">
            <span>Title:</span><textarea id="title-area"></textarea>
            <div><span>Keywords:</span><textarea id="keywords-area"></textarea></div>
            <div id="topic">
                <span>Identify Topic:</span>
                <div id="topicselect-wrap">
                    <div id="topicselect">General</div>
                    <button id="topicselect-btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                    <ul id="topic-list" class="hidden">
                        <li class="topicselectopt-sel">General</li>
                        <li class="topicselectopt">Sports</li>
                        <li class="topicselectopt">Technology</li>
                        <li class="topicselectopt">Politics</li>
                        <li class="topicselectopt">Economy</li>
                        <li class="topicselectopt">Business & Finance</li>
                        <li class="topicselectopt">Entertainment</li>
                        <li class="topicselectopt">Other</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Ribbon">
            <div id="Ribbon-1">
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="SaveButton" title="Save"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div id="Ribbon-1-prev-next">
                    <button class="RibbonBtn" id="UndoButton" title="Undo"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button class="RibbonBtn" id="RedoButton" title="Redo"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Ribbon-2">
                <div class="color-picker" id="color-picker-font">
                    <div id="FontColorButton" class="color-sel" title="Change Font Color"></div>
                    <div class="hidden">
                        <button class="color color1" value="rgb(255,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color2" value="rgb(255,255,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color3" value="rgb(128,255,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color4" value="rgb(0,255,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color5" value="rgb(128,255,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color6" value="rgb(0,128,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color7" value="rgb(255,128,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color8" value="rgb(255,128,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color9" value="rgb(255,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color10" value="rgb(255,255,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color11" value="rgb(128,255,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color12" value="rgb(0,255,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color13" value="rgb(0,255,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color14" value="rgb(0,128,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color15" value="rgb(128,128,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color16" value="rgb(255,0,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color17" value="rgb(128,64,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color18" value="rgb(255,128,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color19" value="rgb(0,255,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color20" value="rgb(0,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color21" value="rgb(0,64,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color22" value="rgb(128,128,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color23" value="rgb(128,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color24" value="rgb(255,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color25" value="rgb(128,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color26" value="rgb(255,128,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color27" value="rgb(0,128,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color28" value="rgb(0,128,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color29" value="rgb(0,0,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color30" value="rgb(0,0,160)"></button>
                        <button class="color color31" value="rgb(128,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color32" value="rgb(128,0,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color33" value="rgb(64,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color34" value="rgb(128,64,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color35" value="rgb(0,64,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color36" value="rgb(0,64,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color37" value="rgb(0,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color38" value="rgb(0,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color39" value="rgb(64,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color40" value="rgb(64,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color41" value="rgb(0,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color42" value="rgb(128,128,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color43" value="rgb(128,128,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color44" value="rgb(128,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color45" value="rgb(64,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color46" value="rgb(192,192,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color47" value="rgb(64,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color48" value="rgb(255,255,255)"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="color-picker" id="color-picker-highlight">
                    <div id="HighlightButton" class="color-sel" title="Highlight Text"></div>
                    <div class="hidden">
                        <button class="color color1" value="rgb(255,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color2" value="rgb(255,255,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color3" value="rgb(128,255,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color4" value="rgb(0,255,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color5" value="rgb(128,255,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color6" value="rgb(0,128,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color7" value="rgb(255,128,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color8" value="rgb(255,128,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color9" value="rgb(255,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color10" value="rgb(255,255,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color11" value="rgb(128,255,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color12" value="rgb(0,255,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color13" value="rgb(0,255,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color14" value="rgb(0,128,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color15" value="rgb(128,128,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color16" value="rgb(255,0,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color17" value="rgb(128,64,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color18" value="rgb(255,128,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color19" value="rgb(0,255,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color20" value="rgb(0,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color21" value="rgb(0,64,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color22" value="rgb(128,128,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color23" value="rgb(128,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color24" value="rgb(255,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color25" value="rgb(128,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color26" value="rgb(255,128,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color27" value="rgb(0,128,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color28" value="rgb(0,128,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color29" value="rgb(0,0,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color30" value="rgb(0,0,160)"></button>
                        <button class="color color31" value="rgb(128,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color32" value="rgb(128,0,255)"></button>
                        <button class="color color33" value="rgb(64,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color34" value="rgb(128,64,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color35" value="rgb(0,64,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color36" value="rgb(0,64,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color37" value="rgb(0,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color38" value="rgb(0,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color39" value="rgb(64,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color40" value="rgb(64,0,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color41" value="rgb(0,0,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color42" value="rgb(128,128,0)"></button>
                        <button class="color color43" value="rgb(128,128,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color44" value="rgb(128,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color45" value="rgb(64,128,128)"></button>
                        <button class="color color46" value="rgb(192,192,192)"></button>
                        <button class="color color47" value="rgb(64,0,64)"></button>
                        <button class="color color48" value="rgb(255,255,255)"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="BoldButton" title="Bold"><i class="fa fa-bold" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="ItalicButton" title="Italic"><i class="fa fa-italic" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="UnderlineButton" title="Underline"><i class="fa fa-underline" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="StrikeButton" title="Strikethrough"><i class="fa fa-strikethrough" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="SupButton" title="Superscript"><i class="fa fa-superscript" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="SubButton" title="Subscript"><i class="fa fa-subscript" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                <div id="font-wrap">
                    <div id="fontselect">Arial</div>
                    <button id="fontselect-btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                    <ul id="font-list" class="hidden">
                        <li class="fontselectopt-sel">Arial</li>
                        <li class="fontselectopt">Calibri</li>
                        <li class="fontselectopt">Consolas</li>
                        <li class="fontselectopt">Cursive</li>
                        <li class="fontselectopt">Georgia</li>
                        <li class="fontselectopt">Monospace</li>
                        <li class="fontselectopt">Tahoma</li>
                        <li class="fontselectopt">Times New Roman</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="fontsize-wrap">
                    <div id="fontsizeselect">4</div>
                    <button id="fontsize-btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <ul id="fontsize-list" class="hidden">
                        <li class="fontsizeselectopt-sel">1</li>
                        <li class="fontsizeselectopt">2</li>
                        <li class="fontsizeselectopt">3</li>
                        <li class="fontsizeselectopt">4</li>
                        <li class="fontsizeselectopt">5</li>
                        <li class="fontsizeselectopt">6</li>
                        <li class="fontsizeselectopt">7</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Ribbon-3">
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="OrderedListButton" title="Numbered List"><i class="fa fa-list-ol" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="UnorderedListButton" title="Bulleted List"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div id="Ribbon-3-Align">
                    <button class="RibbonBtn" id="LeftAlignButton" title="Align Left"><i class="fa fa-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button class="RibbonBtn" id="CenterAlignButton" title="Align Center"><i class="fa fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button class="RibbonBtn" id="RightAlignButton" title="Align Right"><i class="fa fa-align-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button class="RibbonBtn" id="FullAlignButton" title="Align Full"><i class="fa fa-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Ribbon-4">
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="ImageButton" title="Add Image"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="AddLinkButton" title="Add Link"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="RemoveLinkButton" title="Remove Link"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div id="ribbon-corner">
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="preview-btn" title="Preview"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="RibbonBtn" id="submit-btn" title="Submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="TextArea">
            <div id="WYSIWYG" contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null)"></div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div id="preview-wrap">
        <div id="preview-title-wrap">
            <span id="preview-title">Preview</span>
            <span id="preview-topic">Topic</span>
        </div>

        <div id="preview-frame">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var backColor = '#202020';
var fontColor = '#000000';
var fontSize = '4';
var fontFamily = "Arial";

window.addEventListener("load",function(){

    $('#UndoButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Undo",false,null);
    });

    $('#RedoButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Redo",false,null);
    });

    $('#BoldButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Bold", false, null);
    });

    $('#ItalicButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Italic", false, null);
    });

    $('#UnderlineButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Underline", false, null);
    });

    $('#StrikeButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Strikethrough", false, null);
    });

    $('#SupButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Superscript", false, null);
    });

    $('#SubButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Subscript", false, null);
    });

    $('#OrderedListButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("InsertOrderedList", false, "New" + Math.round(Math.random() *1000));
    });

    $('#UnorderedListButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("InsertUnorderedList", false, null);
    });

    $('#LeftAlignButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("justifyLeft", false, null);
    });

    $('#CenterAlignButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("justifyCenter", false, null);
    });

    $('#RightAlignButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("justifyRight", false, null);
    });

    $('#FullAlignButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("justifyFull", false, null);
    });

    $('#AddLinkButton').click(function(){
        var url = prompt("Enter a URL", "http://");
        document.execCommand("CreateLink", false, url);
    });

    $('#RemoveLinkButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("Unlink",false,null);
    });

    $('#ImageButton').click(function(){
        document.execCommand("insertimage",false,"EXAMPLE.jpg");
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".fontselectopt", function() {
        $("#fontselect").html($(this).html());
        $(".fontselectopt-sel").attr("class", "fontselectopt");
        $(this).attr("class", "fontselectopt-sel");
        $('#font-list').attr("class", "hidden");
        $("#fontselect-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        formatDoc("FontName", $(this).html());
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#fontselect-btn", function() {
        if($("#font-list").hasClass("hidden")) {
            $('#font-list').attr("class", "");
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        } else {
            $('#font-list').attr("class", "hidden");
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#fontselect", function() {
        if($("#font-list").hasClass("hidden")) {
            $('#font-list').attr("class", "");
            $("#fontselect-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        } else {
            $('#font-list').attr("class", "hidden");
            $("#fontselect-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".fontsizeselectopt", function() {
        $("#fontsizeselect").html($(this).html());
        $(".fontsizeselectopt-sel").attr("class", "fontsizeselectopt");
        $(this).attr("class", "fontsizeselectopt-sel");
        $('#fontsize-list').attr("class", "hidden");
        $("#fontsize-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        document.formatDoc("FontSize", $(this).html());
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#fontsize-btn", function() {
        if($("#fontsize-list").hasClass("hidden")) {
            $('#fontsize-list').attr("class", "");
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        } else {
            $('#fontsize-list').attr("class", "hidden");
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#fontsizeselect", function() {
        if($("#fontsize-list").hasClass("hidden")) {
            $('#fontsize-list').attr("class", "");
            $("#fontsize-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        } else {
            $('#fontsize-list').attr("class", "hidden");
            $("#fontsize-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        }
    });


    $(document).on("click", "#FontColorButton", function() {
        if($(this).parent().children().hasClass("hidden")) {
            $("#FontColorButton").parent().children(".hidden").attr("class", "color-list");
        } else {
            $("#FontColorButton").parent().children(".color-list").attr("class", "hidden");
        }
    });


    $(document).on("click", "#HighlightButton", function() {
        if($(this).parent().children().hasClass("hidden")) {
            $("#HighlightButton").parent().children(".hidden").attr("class", "color-list");
        } else {
            $("#HighlightButton").parent().children(".color-list").attr("class", "hidden");
        }
    });


    $(document).on('click', "#color-picker-font > .color-list > .color", function () {
        fontColor = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".color-sel").css('background-color', fontColor);
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".color-sel").val(fontColor);
        $(this).parent().attr("class", "hidden");
        document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, fontColor);
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#color-picker-highlight > .color-list > .color", function () {
        backColor = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".color-sel").css('background-color', backColor);
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".color-sel").val(backColor);
        $(this).parent().attr("class", "hidden");
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, backColor);
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#color-picker-font", function() {
        $("#color-picker-highlight > .color-list").attr("class", "hidden");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#color-picker-highlight", function() {
        $("#color-picker-font > .color-list").attr("class", "hidden");
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".topicselectopt", function() {
        $("#topicselect").html($(this).html());
        $(".topicselectopt-sel").attr("class", "topicselectopt");
        $(this).attr("class", "topicselectopt-sel");
        $('#topic-list').attr("class", "hidden");
        $("#topicselect-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#topicselect-btn", function() {    
        if($("#topic-list").hasClass("hidden")) {
            $('#topic-list').attr("class", "");
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        } else {
            $('#topic-list').attr("class", "hidden");
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        }
    });


    $(document).on("click", "#topicselect", function() {
        if($("#topic-list").hasClass("hidden")) {
            $('#topic-list').attr("class", "");
            $("#topicselect-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        } else {
            $('#topic-list').attr("class", "hidden");
            $("#topicselect-btn").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#preview-btn", function() {
        $("#preview-frame").html($("#WYSIWYG").contents().find("body").html());
        var title = $("#title-area").val();
        $("#preview-title").html(title);
        $("#preview-topic").html($("#topicselect").html());
    });


},false);
```